# search filter from multiple select in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

What I'm trying to achieve here is getting filter results from a json file using two dropdown. Actually I have two requirements.

1. Get filtered results on a click of a search button.
2. update the same scope and not creating a new scope for search results.(I have created a new scope in my code)

I'll explain a bit more here I have two select options one is for subjects and other is for grades. I want the results based on the selected options. Eg: If I select Math I should get 2 results as per the json. Also I'm not able to understand how do I achieve the update the view.

Here is code

JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": "images/img01.jpg",
      "title": "Addition and subtraction",
      "subject": "Math",
      "grade": 2,
      "noOfVideos": 1,
      "noOfDocuments": 1,
      "noOfQuestions": 2,
      "date": "21 Dec 2015"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image": "images/img02.jpg",
      "title": "Addition",
      "subject": "Math",
      "grade": 2,
      "noOfVideos": 1,
      "noOfDocuments": 0,
      "noOfQuestions": 1,
      "date": "09 April 2015"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image": "images/img03.jpg",
      "title": "Learn English",
      "subject": "English",
      "grade": 1,
      "noOfVideos": 0,
      "noOfDocuments": 1,
      "noOfQuestions": 1,
      "date": "28 Oct 2015"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "image": "images/img04.jpg",
      "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "subject": "Science",
      "grade": 1,
      "noOfVideos": 1,
      "noOfDocuments": 1,
      "noOfQuestions": 2,
      "date": "11 Jan 2016"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "image": "images/img05.jpg",
      "title": "Computers magic",
      "subject": "Computers",
      "grade": 2,
      "noOfVideos": 1,
      "noOfDocuments": 1,
      "noOfQuestions": 1,
      "date": "01 June 2015"
    }
  ]
}
```

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="search()">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="subject" ng-options="subj.subject for subj in listData">
                <option value="">All Subjects</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="grade" ng-options="grd.grade for grd in listData track by grd.id">
                <option value="">All Grades</option>
            </select>
            <!-- <input type="submit"> -->
            <input type="submit" value="search">
            </form>

            <!-- <div class="item" id="item{{ item }}" ng-repeat="item in listData" draggable item="item">{{ item }}</div> -->
        <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="data in searchResults">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <img ng-show="data.image" src="{{data.image}}" width="120" height="120" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10 data-content">
                    <h1 id="item{{ item }}" class="item" draggable item="item">{{ data.title }}</h1>
                    <p>{{ data.subject }} Grade: {{ data.grade }}</p>
                    <div class="meta-data">
                        <div class="data-details">
                            {{ data.noOfVideos }} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></i> 
                            {{ data.noOfVideos }} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
                            {{ data.noOfVideos }} Q
                        </div>
                        <div class="date">{{ data.date }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default" ng-hide="searchResults" ng-repeat="list in listData">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <img ng-show="list.image" src="{{list.image}}" width="120" height="120" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10 data-content">
                    <h1 id="item{{ item }}" class="item" draggable item="item">{{ list.title }}</h1>
                    <p>{{ list.subject }} Grade: {{ list.grade }}</p>
                    <div class="meta-data">
                        <div class="data-details">
                            {{ list.noOfVideos }} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></i> 
                            {{ list.noOfVideos }} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
                            {{ list.noOfVideos }} Q
                        </div>
                        <div class="date">{{ list.date }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="error" ng-show="error">{{ error }}</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('zayaApp', []);

app.factory('mainInfo', function($http) {
    return $http.get('data.json');
})

app.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'mainInfo', function($scope, $http, mainInfo){

    mainInfo.then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.listData = response.data.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.error = response.statusText;
    });

    $scope.search = function() {
        var searchResults = {
            subject: $scope.subject,
            grade: $scope.grade
        }

        $scope.searchResults = searchResults;
    }


}]);
```

Also if you see the json the grades are repeated so, I wanted to know when populating the select options can I just prevent it from repeating? Only 1 & 2 shows up? I'm able to achieve the results with one dropdown select option but not able to chain it. I would have created a plunkr but it doesn't seems to work with the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Demo Link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1OgUGjt501Y9vbE07In?p=preview)

```
In Angularjs Two way Binding so no need button click. After select dropdown the data will show based on filter...
```

Comment: I cannot change the json is there any other way?

Comment: Why I modified json data means because to avoid few thing 1) avoid duplicate 2) For Dropdown no need to load whole data...

Comment: How can I avoid duplicates? I think there's a way in angularjs and I am able to filter using filters but I need a function to do this i.e if I click on the button the results should show up also the view should update.

Comment: why your going for very difficult way?

Comment: you can avoid duplicates through function it makes performance issue

Comment: we will continue here.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103823/room-for-suresh-b-and-fahad-kazi